# ASP.NET Get data from AD about user

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

Need to identify user on intranet site, windows user name is the goal. That will be appended to params going to SQL Server in the end.

I can get  `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("LOCAL_ADDR")  192.168.112.81`

We have a mixed bag of addresses here, in that 33% are fixed and the rest are allocated.

Is there a recourse to identify the user assigned to an IP  within AD?  If so do you have a link or an example?

TIA.

Comment: What do you mean by "identify the user assigned to an IP within AD"?

Comment: The IP of a current connection is **not** available in AD - AD is a rather static repository of information - it is **not** a "operations management" system that handles dynamic stuff like users logged in and their IP's and stuff like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a page, the username can be found with:

```
Page.User.Identity.Name
```

or

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

or in a service call

```
ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name
```

It will be prefixed by the domain.

Comment: Sorry but I get empty strings with both of these in a page:

Comment: ok, sounds like your site is configured in IIS to allow anonymous access. Look up asp.net Windows authentication setup for asp.net. There's lots of information on it.

Comment: See @blowdart answer - have you configured authentication in your web app?

Answer (score 0):

IPs are not assigned to users, they are assigned to machines. More than one user can use a machine, so your approach makes no sense.

Instead configure [Windows Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx) on your site and then you can use the [User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.user.aspx) property within an MVC controller or the [User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.user.aspx) property in a webforms page. Both these properties return an [IPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.user.aspx) which in turn has an [Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.identity.aspx) property, which is an [IIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.aspx) instance. The [name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.name.aspx) property of the identity will give you the user's account name.

Comment: Thanks.  I am looking to that now.